# How to handle possible duplicate content across multiple sites?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, local-seo

Let's say I have two sites that cover the same vertical/topic. one in the USA and one in Canada.  Both sites have local-related content, which is obviously unique by location.  However they will share common news or blog pages.

How do I avoid getting hit with duplicate content on both sites for those news/blog pages?

If the content is exactly the same, I'm guessing I would have to pick which site's content I want to noindex,nofollow, is that correct, and if so, is that all I have to add on the URL links to those pages, and the pages' meta tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [canonical tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) to tell the search engines that it is the same content, but on a different URL

Also consider using the [source tag](http://searchengineland.com/google-creates-metatags-to-help-id-original-news-sources-56115)

Comment: The link you provided refers to pages on the same website, where-as in my example, the pages on completely separate websites.

Comment: @ElHaix It is good for different domains too. see the last Q&A on the page

Comment: @ElHaix Updated the answer